# Regex - Match everything after second occurence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have the following string:

```
"http://sprzedajemy.pl/http://soloch.sprzedajemy.pl/renault-scenic-i-grafitowy,10395187"
```

Now, I want to match everything after the second occurrence of "http://", which I tried like this without any success:

```
/(http:\/\/){2}(.+)/
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quantifying the group `http://` twice instead of skipping to the second occurence. Use this regular expression:

```
/^(?:http:\/\/(.+)){2}/
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/yX3eB5/3)!

Comment: If there's an https over here ur regex doesnot work :)

Comment: @vks If it's necessary, we can expand the regex by replacing `http` with `(?:https?|ftp)`... But I'd like to follow the specifications.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below regex to match the string which was after just after to the second `http://`,

```
(?<=http:\/\/)(?:(?!http:\/\/).)*$
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/Qq2xeeQ8av)

If you want to capture the string then try the below,

```
(?<=http:\/\/)((?:(?!http:\/\/).)*)$
```

[DEMO](http://www.rubular.com/r/QEI9O0InZp)

Answer (score 1):

```
  http.*?http\:\/\/(.*)
```

This should do it.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bZ9kJ0/1

```
 (?!http.*?http.*)http\:\/\/(.*)
```

Use this to ignore https if its there in first position.