# Regex - Match everything after second comma (or comma and space)

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I looked at this link: [Regex - Match everything after second occurence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504487/regex-match-everything-after-second-occurence). I cannot seem to substitute the http:// for a comma, let alone a comma and space. This is a sample of a string that I am working with:

> 42: A: b41a2431, B: 7615239a, we, are(the champion 12 .)

I am looking to extract **anything** after the second ", "...

So, that would be:

> we, are(the champion 12 .)

(If it helps, I will be doing this in Python.)

Answer (score 0):

The regex doesn't work for you since the case is a bit different
That regex assumes the strings **starts** with http(s)://
If all the test strings have 2 commas then the regex is very simple
`.*?,.*?,(.+)`
*? means lazy (vs greedy) quantifier so it will not eat the next comma (since it fits the "any character" `.`)

you can see the demo here https://regex101.com/r/XjLOVz/1

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use split() and join()?

```
string = "42: A: b41a2431, B: 7615239a, we, are(the champion 12 .)"
result = ", ".join(string.split(", ")[2:])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
'we, are(the champion 12 .)'
```

Answer (score 0):

full code example using re

1. **[^,]+** all symbols without comma
2. **,**   comma symbol
3. **[^,]+** all symbols without comma
4. **,**   comma symbol
5. **\s*** 0 or more whitespaces
6. **(.+)** useful data

```
import re
data="42: A: b41a2431, B: 7615239a, we, are(the champion 12 .)"
re.findall(r'[^,]+,[^,]+,\s*(.+)',data)
```

otput

```
['we, are(the champion 12 .)']
```